# Create Array Using JSON Results

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Im trying to query an API 
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=XRP,BTC,ETH,BCH&tsyms=USD

The results are in teh following format 
DISPLAY:XRP:USD:CHANGEPCT24HR
The above is the item i want to create an array of although XRP will re replaced with each fsyms value

This is my code so far

```
  $json_string =    file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=XRP&tsyms=USD");
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
  $btcp = $parsed_json['DISPLAY']['XRP']['USD']; 
  $btcchange = $parsed_json['DISPLAY']['XRP']['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR'];
```

I know I shouldnt post "how do i" questions 
but there are so many possible methods jquery(map) toArray etc i just dont know where to start

Comment: Basically you just want to fetch the data from that URL using jQuery? If yes, try using [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: not doing anything
will look into that cheers

Comment: $.get(URL).done(function(resp) { console.log(resp); }) gives out the response. Did you try this?

Comment: DISPLAY
:
XRP
:
USD
:
CHANGE24HOUR
:
"$ -0.0045"
CHANGEDAY
:
"$ -0.0072"
CHANGEPCT24HOUR
:
"-1.85"
CHANGEPCTDAY
:
"-2.92"
FROMSYMBOL
:
"XRP"
HIGH24HOUR
:
"$ 0.2473"
HIGHDAY
:
"$ 0.2469"
LASTMARKET
:
"Exmo"
LASTTRADEID
:
"28438827"
LASTUPDATE
:
"Just now"
LASTVOLUME
:
"XRP 214.08"
LASTVOLUMETO
:
"$ 51.74"
LOW24HOUR
:
"$ 0.2347"
LOWDAY
:
"$ 0.2352"
MARKET
:
"CryptoCompare Index"
MKTCAP
:
"$ 9,155.10 M"
OPEN24HOUR
:
"$ 0.2435"
OPENDAY
:
"$ 0.2462"
PRICE
:
"$ 0.2390"
SUPPLY
:
"XRP 38,305,873,865.0"

Comment: Right, it's an object. So now what? You want it to be an array?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the DISPLAY:XXX:USD:CHANGEPCT24HOUR value for each value (XXX replace with BTC, XRP any value sent in the url that is passed in the fsysm value)
something like
$coins['XRP']['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR'];
$coins['BTC']['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR'];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160541/discussion-between-shashank-and-chris-yates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution to create an array (mapped based on jQuery parameters sent to the AJAX call).

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/5euk7w3k/)

**Relevant code:**

```
var fsyms = 'XRP,BTC,BCH', tsyms = 'USD', change_attr = 'CHANGEPCT24HOUR', values = [];

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull',
  data: {
    fsyms: fsyms, tsyms: tsyms
  }
}).done(function (resp) {
   console.log(resp);
   var display_val = resp['DISPLAY'];
   fsyms.split(',').map(function(d) { 
   values.push({name: d, value: display_val[d][tsyms][change_attr]});
});

 console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: Cheers mate will accept that now
is it possible to sort the array by highest value ?
What I want to do ideally is shove this inside a setInterval and get it to query the URL every x amount of seconds which will then display the percentage change in real-time